# Flutter app cannot run on iOS14 real device

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie,I used iOS14 and I've a problem when I try run app after built on iOS14. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to low-level changes in iOS’s debugger mechanisms, developers using versions of Flutter earlier than 1.20.4 stable won’t be able to launch apps (by using flutter run or a Flutter-enabled IDE) on physical iOS devices running iOS 14. This affects debug, profile, and release builds. Simulator builds, add-to-app modules, and running directly from Xcode are unaffected.

Upgrading to Flutter 1.22 beta allows you to build, test, and deploy to iOS without issue. Upgrading to 1.20.4 stable allows you to build and deploy to iOS 14, but not debug.

source: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14

Comment: Have 1.22.6 and i see this screen. it seems it is broken again?

Answer (score 4):

The application cannot be opened via the homescreen if installed in debug mode. use `flutter run --release` or `flutter run --profile` first.